# How do you update your app in the Android Emulator with changes you just saved?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

How do you update your app in the Android Emulator with changes you just saved while the AVD is still running? That is, without restarting the virtual device?

For example, let's say that I have an Android app that just says "Hello world!".

If I update that string to say "Hello world! Have a nice day.", how can I ensure that the change takes effect without restarting the AVD?

Initial Code:

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
```

Updated Code:

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello world! Have a nice day.</string>
```

Comment: android studio new version have new feature which is called instant run which do exactly what you want

Comment: update android studioo and try to run your code it will upaddte wihout restaring avd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new versions of Android Studio, quickly updating your Android app without restarting your emulator is easy.

However, you still need to press the debug button again. After the first run the lightning bolt will appear next to the bug in the debug button.

[image: InstantRun]

Simply make your changes, click the 'instant run' button above (circled in yellow), and voila.

Thanks Younas!